# how can I make the resulting combinations appear in a column without brackets, without commas and without spaces?

Tags: python

```
import itertools
val = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
perm_set = itertools.permutations(val, 8)
for i in perm_set:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Please either ask your question in English or post on https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ if you prefer

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not in English. Please try [ru.so].

Comment: You mention wanting to display **combinations** but you are using **permutations** in your code. Can you please provide an example of your desired output?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but does this work?

```
import itertools 
val = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0] 
perm_set = itertools.permutations(val, 8) 
for i in perm_set: 
    print(*i, sep="") # Edited as recommended by @ddejohn
```

Output:

```
12345678
12345679
...
12345879
12345870
```

Comment: You can actually just use `print(*i, sep="")`.